# lit error upgrading from 23.2.8 to 23.3.5

Tags: vaadin

I got the following error:

[image]

I tried unsuccessful:

- mvn vaadin:dance
- delete package.json, mvn clean install

My versions are Vaadin 23.3.5, java 17 and Selenium 4.5.3

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Likely your package.json contains lit-html 1.x or lit-element 2.x where Vaadin 23.3.5 depends on lit 2.x which means lit-html 2.x and lit-element 3.x

If removing and re-generating package.json does not help, it is likely a class in your project or in an add-on that contains an `@NpmPackage` annotation for lit-html or lit-element.

Comment: Thanks Artur! It works.
I didn't found any @NpmPackage in my code, so I checked my addons. 
I've just upgraded the following addon: org.vaadin.klaudeta grid-pagination to 3.0.0.
The problem has been resolved!